# How to use a custom corefx build in .net core application

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I changed few classes in the 'corefx' source code, build and run unit tests.
Everything went well and now I have my custom 'corefx' build.

Now I need to try to use the customized 'corefx' build in my test .net core application. 
What should I do? 
Is there any guidelines for my purposes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official docs (which may be out of date) are here: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/project-docs/dogfooding.md#more-advanced-scenario---using-your-local-corefx-build.

To summarize:

1. Set a non-zero build number
2. Build CoreFx
3. Add the built CoreFx packages to your NuGet feed
4. Change your dependencies to require the version of the packages you just built
5. Rebuild your project

Depending on what you are trying to do, an easier alternative may be to [build the entire .NET Core project](https://github.com/dotnet/source-build/), which will include any of your modifications to corefx.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've seen the document that you mentioned but didn't try to follow the instructions from it.
But is there other way ( for example, some environment variable ) which allows me to say 'I wan to use corefx build from this folder for current project'?

Comment: Sadly, I know of no other way. Like you, I have found it very difficult to assemble bits and pieces out of the various .NET Core repositories selectively.