# Compiling and using custom Dotnet/CoreFx

Tags: .net-core

I have pull https://github.com/dotnet/corefx made some modifications on System.Net.Requests and build using "build -allconfigurations"

Using visual code i have test the modifications running the included tests as explained here:
https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/project-docs/developer-guide.md

Question : How can i use the version that i built on a console app?

I have follow this instructions [How to use a custom corefx build in .net core application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49771507/how-to-use-a-custom-corefx-build-in-net-core-application) without success. Is still loading default netcore 3 and not my version, debug shows:

> (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.0.0\System.Net.Requests.dll'

My modifications are not working.

Comment: Use `dotnet publish --self-contained` to publish all binaries, and replace `System.Net.Request` with your own copy there.

Comment: Well, that works, but there's any way to debug my project using my own system.net,requests with visual studio?

Comment: Launch your patched application first, and then attach the debugger to it. I don't know any easier way, because by default VS and .NET Core SDK assumes you use a standard build of .NET Core.